# Citation behind a display equation

Tags: citations

I occasionally have a case where I want to give a formula and also attribute it. This ends up like that:

[image]

I do not really like that, though. The citation looks very odd at this spot. If the next paragraph would continue right after the citation mark, it would be worse, I fear.

- One solution would be to just attach the citation mark at the end of the sentence, perhaps even after a colon behind “by”. This does not really make sense from a reading-flow perspective.
- One could also try to mangle in another sentence, attribute that and give the equation afterwards. That would look nicer but not be correct.
- Alternatively, we can use the `\textcite` command from `biblatex` which will produce

  > Schatz, Weidinger, Deicher [SWD10]

  instead and can by used in the text like

  > the factor is given by Schatz, Weidinger, Deicher [SWD10] as EQUATION.

  Or one could append that like this:

  > the factor is given by EQUATION as given by Schatz, Weidinger, Deicher [SWD10].

What would be a good solution that is both scientifically correct and also the least ugly?

Comment: I think you've already answered your own question with your suggestions at the end.  Personally, I prefer your last option, where the equation is embedded in a sentence.  That's because I don't like putting a period at the end of an equation (since the period is not part of the equation).  But your second-to-last option would work well also.  I would never try to stick a citation on an equation.  Too ugly.  (p.s. 30 years of scientific publishing experience)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second option is one I have seen frequently.  As an example of its use, have a look at page 19 of http://arxiv.org/abs/1501.07274, just above their equation (2.3), where they use that format of citation for a formula.  (Never forget, though, that citation style is usually dictated by the journal you are submitting to.  Be certain to check *their* editorial and style guidelines for the context-dependent answer to your question.)